# Oracle Apex javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I'm using below `javascript` to set value to cell in a `tabular` form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventListener(pThis)
{

$('input[name="f04"]').change(function(){

var that = this;
var vRow = "f10_"+pThis.id.substr(pThis.id.indexOf('_')+1);

$.post("wwv_flow.show", 
       {p_request      : "APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_AMOUNT",
        p_flow_id      : $v("pFlowId"),
        p_flow_step_id : $v("pFlowStepId"),
        p_instance     : $v("pInstance"),
        x01            : $(this).val()
        },
        function(data){ 
              $('input[id="f10_0002"]').val(data);
        },
        "text"
      );
});

}
</script>
```

I need to use value in `var vRow` instead of `f10_0002` in `$('input[id="f10_0002"]').val(data);`.

I have tried with `$('input[id=vRow]').val(data);` and `$('input[id='"'+vRow+'"']').val(data);`

But doesn't work. javascript is not worked in these situations. but `$('input[id="f10_0002"]').val(data);` is worked.

how could i use value in `var vRow` for this ?

Comment: Don't use `$("input[id=" + value + "]")`...just use `$("#" + value)`

Comment: @lan why ? can you explain the reason ?

Comment: `#` is the equivalent of matching an element by ID. That is its purpose in jQuery selection. If you look at the jQuery selectors page ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ), you'll see there are several special characters to help with selecting elements. As I said, `#` is for ID, `.` is for class, etc. So instead of having jQuery parse the string "input[id=value]" and do a lot of extra processing, you can help jQuery do it more efficiently by simply using `#`. IDs are supposed to be unique and the method `document.getElementById`, which I'm sure jQuery uses internally, is "better"

Comment: @lan post your comment as a answer. i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the selector `input[id=value]` is technically right (because of the jQuery attribute selector), it isn't necessary. The main reason is because you're targeting an element by ID. Javascript has a special method that is especially fast, which I'm sure jQuery uses internally ( `document.getElementById` ) when you specify you're selecting by ID. To trigger the selection of an element by ID, you can use the `#` character at the beginning of the selector string. Since you are trying to use the value of a variable as well, you can concatenate `"#"` and `vRow`, like:

```
$("#" + vRow).val(data);
```

`#` is the equivalent of matching an element by ID. If you look at the jQuery selectors page ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors ), you'll see there are several special characters to help with selecting elements. As I said, `#` is for ID...`.` is for class, etc. So instead of having jQuery parse the string "input[id=value]" and do a lot of extra processing, you can help jQuery do it more efficiently by simply using `#`.

Comment: @lan i use this javascript for `change` event of `f04` row in my tabular form. this row is a `autocomplete` row. when i select item from `autocomplete` list, this javascript is not working. value is not set to the relevant field. but when i type item name with out selecting it from `autocomplete` list, it works. what could be the issue ?

Comment: This my code. Download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vq3yralf5qzxjtd/jQuery_Ajax.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input[id="' + vRow + '"]').val(data);
```